# Why is my scrollWidth showing wrong number? React JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**What I am trying to do**
I am building a Netflix clone using React JS.
I have made a list of video component to list video items horizontally. I've set the container's overflow-x to hidden, so I can use the left and right buttons to scroll left and right. And by having boolean value of isOverflowLeft and isOverflowRight, I wanted to make the button display: none when there is no overflow. I am using useRef() to make this function works. When either the left or right button clicks, scrollLeft updates to either +- 400.

**Problem**
The problem is when the component is rendered, scrollWidth is showing a different number. In my case, scrollWidth should be 4000, but it's showing the same width as clientWidth. Can you please check my code and teach me what I am doing wrong?

```js
const VideoList = memo(({ label, fetchUrl, isLarge }) => {
  const listRef = useRef();
  const [isOverflowLeft, setIsOverflowLeft] = useState(false);
  const [isOverflowRight, setIsOverflowRight] = useState(false);
  const [scrollLeft, setScrollLeft] = useState(0);

  const handleScrollRight = () => {
    if (isOverflowRight) {
      listRef.current.scrollLeft += 400;
      setScrollLeft((prev) => prev + 400);
    }
  };
  const handleScrollLeft = () => {
    if (isOverflowLeft) {
      listRef.current.scrollLeft -= 400;
      setScrollLeft((prev) => prev - 400);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow',
      };
      await fetch(fetchUrl, requestOptions)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setMovies(data.results))
        .catch((error) => console.log('error', error));
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchUrl]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOverflowLeft(scrollLeft > 0);
    setIsOverflowRight(
      scrollLeft + listRef.current.clientWidth < listRef.current.scrollWidth
    );
    console.log(
      `clientWidth: ${listRef.current.clientWidth} scrollWidth: ${listRef.current.scrollWidth} scrollLeft: ${scrollLeft} isOverflowLeft: ${isOverflowLeft} isOverflowRight: ${isOverflowRight}`
    );
  }, [scrollLeft, isOverflowLeft, isOverflowRight]);

  return (
    <section className={styles.container}>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>{label}</h1>
      <div className={styles.list} ref={listRef}>
        <button
          className={isOverflowLeft ? styles.scrollLeft : styles.hidden}
          onClick={handleScrollLeft}
        >
          <BsChevronCompactLeft className={styles.scrollIcon} />
        </button>
        {movies.map((movie) => {
          return <VideoItem key={movie.id} video={movie} isLarge={isLarge} />;
        })}
        <button
          className={isOverflowRight ? styles.scrollRight : styles.hidden}
          onClick={handleScrollRight}
        >
          <BsChevronCompactRight className={styles.scrollIcon} />
        </button>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
});

export default memo(VideoList);
```

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: Can you convert your code to a working snippet so we can inspect for ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, i found a workaround, i wanted to set a constraint to a slider by calculating the width that is left to scroll and update it. Apparently the problem is as soon as the page is rendered .scrollWidth and .offsetWidth/.clientWidth return the same value. so i added a small delay before executing what's inside useEffect and it worked.
Here is what my code looks like :

```js
 const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const carousel = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setWidth(carousel.current.scrollWidth - carousel.current.offsetWidth);
    }, 2000);
  }, [carousel]);
```

Answer (score 1):

same problem here, but i learned that you can use `requestAnimationFrame` to get correct and accurate `scrollWidth` inside `useEffect`.

```js
useEfect(() => {
    ...

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        // get DOM node's height, width, top, left, right and bottom here.
        exampleElementRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    })

    ...
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `listRef.current` to useEffect dependencies array, because it's look like
`listRef.current` value changes when the list elem gets overflowed and then it will give you the correct `.scrollWidth` value. so your code should look like this:

```
... 
useEffect(() => {
    setIsOverflowLeft(scrollLeft > 0);
    setIsOverflowRight(
      scrollLeft + listRef.current.clientWidth < listRef.current.scrollWidth
    );
    console.log(
      `clientWidth: ${listRef.current.clientWidth} scrollWidth: ${listRef.current.scrollWidth} scrollLeft: ${scrollLeft} isOverflowLeft: ${isOverflowLeft} isOverflowRight: ${isOverflowRight}`
    );
  }, [listRef.current, scrollLeft, isOverflowLeft, isOverflowRight]);
...
```